# Move a marker based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

basically I am trying to move a marker (or any shape like a circle or whatever) based on a cell which can have a value between 8 and 24. Imagine like a reverse slider which moves from left to right based on that cell value.

See example
[image]

Is that somehow possible without VBA/Macros? Thanks.

Comment: There may be some options in Conditional Formatting that may do something similar to what you want (Data Bar, maybe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help but I figured out a way. In case anyone is interested, here it is:
Create a X-Y Scatter (the basic one). Right click and press "Select data", then "Add".
For "Series X values" select the cell that contains the value you want represented. Leave the rest as is. (See screenshot)

[image: p1]

Click "ok" and again "ok".

Right click the chart and select "format plot area" to and go to "axis options". Set the bounds to your required values.

Click on the "+" sign next to the chart and unselect everything there.

Right click the chart, "format plot area". On top, go through all the options (chart area, plot area, series 1), and set "fill" and "border" to "no fill", "no border".
It should look like this:

[image: p2]

Now go to "series options", "fill and line", "marker", "marker options", and choose the marker you want.

Resize the graph to approximately the height of a cell and put it above the scale you want. The final result looks like this.

[image: p3]

[image: p4]

Answer (score 1):

The "OG" way would be to place a formula in the leftmost cell that placed a character that would be the slider and spaces to move it rightward as appropriate.

One could do that over three cells, or merge them, or one cell if the lower cells could be adjusted to have their effects in a single cell.

For three cells like shown:

```
=REPT(" ",  E1-1-7)  &  "t"
```

(The red cell would be D1 in the formula example so the 15 is in E1.)

The formula would go in the green cell and the green/yellow/red cells would need to be empty otherwise.

You would format for a symbol font, in this case Wingdings, font size (11 for me), column width (9 for me), and so on. More subtle is that adjusting cell width is not the only way to fit the "slider." I used a single space for the repeating character, above, but multiple spaces could be used, or any other character that is blank. Some are narrower or wider than others, so the left-right size of a full slider (24) would fit neatly, no extra space past where it hits its maximum rightward movement.

And one could use a different kind of character altogether to give it a trail behind the marker.

The `"t"` at the end was character `0x74` in the Wingdings font from Character Map, not a `t`. *(Can you believe it's been 35 years and no one's made a replacement for CM that gives the decimal values you need for typing them?)*

In the old days, it was the asterisk that would have likely been used or one of the text-based screen characters for boxes and such, to make a bar though, not a marker moving left-to-right.

Charts and sparklines were unsatisfactory because they "naturally" move up/down, not left/right.

One COULD, probably set up a three cell chart input range using the changing value and a left and right offset aimed at driving the marker character (middle cell in the input range) left and right as needed, but the above is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's actually really good! I found a different way using graphs (see my answer), but yours is more simplistic. Mine allows a bit more choice in the type of symbol I can use and the placement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Icon sets** to help you, go to **Home**- **Styles: Conditional Formatting**- **Icon sets**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this allows me to move said icons. Anyway I found a solution using a scatter plot (see my answer if you want).